# InvalidDigit while converting vector of strings to vector of u32 in Rust

Tags: string, loops, rust

I am trying to convert a vector of strings to a vector of u32, but I keep getting the InvalidDigit error.

The vector of strings is completely filled with numbers as strings, and there are *no* words or characters in them.

Here's my code:

```
struct DayTwo { 
    input: String
}

impl DayTwo { 
    pub fn get_values(&self, filter: &str) -> Vec<u32> { 
        let input: Vec<u32> = self.input
            .split("\n")
            .into_iter()
            .filter(|n| n.starts_with(filter))
            .map(|x| x.trim_start_matches(filter))
            .map(|n| n.parse::<u32>().unwrap())
            .collect();

        for num in &input{ 
            println!("{}", num);
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src/main.rs:11:163
```

Comment: Why not put a print before the panicking line to confirm? `println!("str='{}'",str);` and then share what it prints?

Comment: Add `trim` probably you are just trying to parse with the newlines `.map(|x| x.trim())`

Comment: @RossRogers I did not want to post the ouput of that because there's 100+ numbers, but I can confirm that all strings in the vector are numbers.

Comment: @Netwave I don't think I understand why that would help. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: you strings could be `"10\n"` and that would make it fail the parse. You need to trim them.

Comment: @Netwave but wouldn't split("\n") take care of that?

Comment: actually, yes, it should.

Comment: I figured it out (with some help lol)! Turns out there was a space before each number, so adding trim() to the second map function solved my problem!

Comment: @CaioIshikawa you can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! When separating the string (e.g "forward 6") into just the integer, I left the space between the word and the number, so I had to add trim() to the second map function to get rid of the empty space.